# More concise way to count no. of lessons/events held if multiple per date exist

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, aggregate-functions, mariadb-10.3

This is an example for the question's sake, but I basically have MySQL data similar to the following:

| ID | LessonDate | PersonID | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-01-11 | 1 | Spanish |
| 1235 | 2021-01-11 | 1 | Spanish |
| 1236 | 2021-01-11 | 2 | Spanish |
| 1237 | 2021-01-12 | 1 | Music |
| 1238 | 2021-01-12 | 1 | Music |
| 1239 | 2021-01-12 | 1 | Music |
| 1240 | 2021-01-12 | 3 | Music |
| 1241 | 2021-01-12 | 3 | Music |
| 1242 | 2021-01-13 | 2 | Chemistry |
| 1243 | 2021-01-13 | 3 | Chemistry |
| 1244 | 2021-01-13 | 2 | Spanish |
| 1245 | 2021-01-14 | 3 | Mathematics |

This is interpreted to mean that:

- Person 1 had two Spanish lessons on 11th Jan (Person 2 attended one of those)
- Person 1 had three Music lessons on 12th Jan (Person 3 attended two of those)
- Person 2 and Person 3 shared a Chemistry lesson on 13th Jan, while only Person 2 went to Spanish that day, etc.

To get my desired output I'm currently using 4 levels of grouping as follows. Starting with a count per subject-person-date, then the max per subject per date, then the total per subject, and finally listing out the subjects for each total:

```
SELECT LessonsHeld, GROUP_CONCAT(Subject ORDER BY Subject SEPARATOR ', ') AS Subjects FROM
    (SELECT Subject, SUM(DayCount) AS LessonsHeld FROM
        (SELECT Subject, LessonDate, MAX(PersonDayCount) AS DayCount FROM
            (SELECT Subject, LessonDate, PersonID, COUNT(*) AS PersonDayCount FROM `lessons`
            GROUP BY Subject, LessonDate, PersonID) x           
        GROUP BY Subject, LessonDate) y     
    GROUP BY Subject) z
GROUP BY LessonsHeld
ORDER BY LessonsHeld DESC
```

The output:

```
[LessonsHeld]    [Subjects]
3                Music, Spanish
1                Chemistry, Mathematics
```

Is there a more concise way to count people's multiple events/classes etc. held on given dates? 4 levels of `GROUP BY` seems a tad extreme here.

Note the reason I have multiple IDs for single events is that each attendee can enter and delete their own data. I've focused on minimising data entry rather than having them do anything extra such as remembering start times or matching up their attendance with each other.

Comment: Please tag your MySql version!

Comment: @Stu Ok. I'm on MariaDB 10.3 at the oldest, but I'm curious to see approaches for other versions/engines regardless.

Answer (score 1):

MySql 8.0 supports window functions, so it can be a bit shorter

```
SELECT LessonsHeld, GROUP_CONCAT(Subject ORDER BY Subject SEPARATOR ', ') AS Subjects 
FROM
    (SELECT Subject, SUM(DayCount) AS LessonsHeld 
     FROM 
           (SELECT Subject, LessonDate,  
               max(COUNT(*)) over(partition by Subject, LessonDate) AS DayCount,
               row_number() over(partition by Subject, LessonDate order by PersonID) rn
            FROM `lessons`
            GROUP BY Subject, LessonDate, PersonID
            ) x  
    where rn = 1      
    GROUP BY Subject) z
GROUP BY LessonsHeld
ORDER BY LessonsHeld DESC;
```

Not sure if it will perform better.

[MariaDB 10.3 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f07fabe9d9453bf2319b401df2999fef)